# Transfer a file between sandboxed processes on 10.12 Sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos, appstore-sandbox, macos-sierra

I have 2 sandboxed applications in a single App Group and trying to transfer a file, produced in the "Main"(SandboxTest in code) application to "Helper"(SandboxPair in code) application. With sandbox it works on 10.11 and fails on 10.12 Sierra. Also works fine when sandbox is off.

Helper is launched by Main using NSTask (I also tried NSWorkspace with same result). Here is how I launch it and send a file:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{       
    //Testing
    _path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SandboxPair" ofType:@"app"];
    _path = [_path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Contents/MacOS/SandboxPair"];
    if( ![self runTaskWithLaunchPath:_path] ) {
        NSLog(@"launching helper app failed");
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(sendFile) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];

    return;
}

- (BOOL)runTaskWithLaunchPath:(NSString*)launchPath
{
    _helperAppTask = [NSTask new];
    if( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:launchPath] )
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Not found command %@", launchPath);
        return NO;
    }

    _helperAppTask.launchPath = launchPath;

    NSPipe* outPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSPipe* errPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    _helperAppTask.standardOutput = outPipe;
    _helperAppTask.standardError = errPipe;

    [_helperAppTask launch];

    return YES;
}

///Run openFile:withApplication: test
- (void)sendFile
{
    NSString* groupIdentifier = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"AppIdentifierPrefix"]
                                stringByAppendingString:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleIdentifierKey]];
    NSURL* sharedPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                         containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:groupIdentifier];

    NSError* error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:sharedPath
                             withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    NSString* fileName = @"test.txt";

    fileName = [[@"~/Downloads/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    [@"test file" writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES
                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"File written at path: %@", fileName);

    BOOL opened = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:fileName withApplication:_path];

    if(!opened) {
        NSLog(@"File was not opened in helper application");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File was successfully opened in helper application");
    }
}
```

The receive file code from helper application's AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    alert.messageText = @"Helper app: File was recieved. application:openFile: is working";
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert runModal];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray<NSString *> *)filenames
{
    NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    alert.messageText = @"Helper app: Files was recieved. application:openFiles: is working";
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

You can see test project on github: https://github.com/pogosskiy/SierraSandbox
There is also a code to test NSConnection between these processes. I tried to use it to indicate application that there is a file in Group Container, but it also fails on 10.12 under sandbox.

How can i fix this project? Maybe there is some sandbox flag in entitlements? I already tried some in com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events, but with no effect (or maybe a have a mistake there).